# Taking a 2D array and merging it into one

Tags: c, arrays, memory-layout

I am trying to figure out how to merge a 2D array into one.

I have a 2D array that looks as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROW 2
#define COL 10

int
main(void)
{
  int array[ROW][COL] = {2,6,12,18,23,55,57,58,59,60} , {1,3,5,9,11,19,27,28,31,56};
}
```

I was trying to use a nested for loop but wasn't having any luck.

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are having, but your initializer syntax needs an extra set of curly braces around the two member initializers.  If that does not resolve your issue then please present a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `merge a 2D array into one` You have to define what this means.

Comment: how do you wish to merge it? first number of first array, first number of 2nd array, 2nd number of 1st array, 2nd number of 2nd array and so on?

Comment: This `int array[ROW][COL] = {2,6,12,18,23,55,57,58,59,60} , {1,3,5,9,11,19,27,28,31,56};` is not valid C.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
#include <string.h> /* for memcpy() */

#define ROW (2)
#define COL (10)

int main(void)
{
  int array[ROW][COL] = {
    {  2,  6, 12, 18, 23, 55, 57, 58, 59, 60}, 
    {  1,  3,  5,  9, 11, 19, 27, 28, 31, 56}
  };

  int array1D[ROW*COL];
  memcpy(array1D, array, ROW*COL * sizeof(int));
}
```

In C array elements are guaranteed to be placed in memory in a successive way (no padding!). So simply copying the memory should do.

Comment: Simple yet effective.

Answer (score 0):

`memcpy` isn't guaranteed to work. You're technically making an array of arrays, and depending on how the memory for each individual "linear" array is allocated, `memcpy` may or may not work. It likely **will** with the way you have it allocated, but it's not guaranteed.

This is what you were trying to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROW 2
#define COL 10

int
main(void)
{
  int array[ROW][COL] ={ {2,6,12,18,23,55,57,58,59,60} , {1,3,5,9,11,19,27,28,31,56}};

  int i,j;

  int array1D[ROW*COL];

  for (i=0; i<ROW; i++){
        for (j=0; j<COL; j++){
            array1D[i*COL+j]=array[i][j];
        }
   }

   for (i=0; i<ROW*COL; i++){
      printf("%d ",array1D[i]);
   }

}
```

Note that here, `i` represents the row and `j` the column. To access an individual `int` and maintain the "2d" nature, the index would be `row #*column length+column #`. Or `i*COL+j`

Comment: An array of arrays is exactly what is commonly and most correctly called a "2D array" in C.  I think you're confusing it with an array of pointers, which is indeed different, though it can be accessed with similar syntax.  All the `int` the elements in the OP's member arrays are guaranteed to be laid out sequentially in memory, and the two member arrays are also guaranteed to be laid out sequentially.

Comment: True. What I was trying to emphasize is that it's not an independent concept like a matrix is in matlab or other languages. Array[A][B] isn't accessing "point A,B." You're getting the value of index B in array A. I'll edit that part out.

Comment: You've taken the terminology point, but seem to have missed the more significant language semantics point: there is no ambiguity or question about how the members of the OPs array are laid out in memory, unless you want to talk about details of the representation of type `int`.  The first 1D array is first, at the lowest address of the 2D array, and the second follows immediately with no padding before or after.  Within each, the `int` elements are laid out consecutively, again with no padding.  This arrangement is indistinguishable from that of a 1D array of `ROW*COL` ints.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* merge nbyA bytes of data in a with nbyB bytes of data in b. Return result. */
void *merge(const void *a, size_t nbyA, const void *b, size_t nbyB)
{
    void *buf = malloc(nbyA + nbyB);
    if (buf) {
        memcpy(buf, a, nbyA);
        memmove(buf + nbyA, b, nbyB);
    }

    return buf; /* caller must free */
}
```

To `a` pass `array[0]`; to `b` pass `array[1]`.

The advantage of this solution is that you have a generalized `merge` function that can be used for more than just merging two subarrays of a 2D array, but for merging any two blocks of data.